# get list of cities under province

Tags: android, geocoding, city

Is it possible on Android to get the list of the cities by province?
I thought it was possible to do it by Google APIs but i didn't find anything.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just province without database. though it's possible to find all cities with the country name by google API. if you want it by county I can post the code !

Answer (score 0):

You look for a gazetteer service, for example [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) to solve your problem. 
You need to have an ID of the "province", as names are ambiguous and have variations. Also, if you record any user choices, make sure you store the ID and not the string associated with the entity.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm I think this can help ^_^

http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

at this link there are almost every names present or you can use  Yahoo!'s GeoPlanet for it .. either downloading or using the api :-)

[developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet)

Answer (score 0):

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) has many features that you can use them. for example there is :
[Java Client](http://www.geonames.org/source-code/)